# Retrieve without timestamp

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to fetch updated_at without timestamp in order by but unable to do so. I am using date_trunc function but unable to get proper result.Apart from this is there any other function which can give me only date not timestamp

```
users = User.members(current_user,params).order("date_trunc('datepart', updated_at) DESC, upvotes DESC").paginate(:per_page => PER_PAGE,:page => (params[:page] || 1))
```

Comment: `User.pluck(:updated_at).map { |date| Date.parse(date) }.sort`

Comment: Is `datepart` a valid value for `date_trunc`?  The [Postgres Date/Time docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) mention 'day', not 'datepart'.

Comment: yeah it is not valid that is why i  was getting an error

Comment: @prateek have you tried `date_trunc('day', updated_at)`?

Comment: yes I have already tried that but it didn't gave me the right response

Comment: @prateek that is a bit vague, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following.

```
users = User.members(current_user,params).order("updated_at.to_date DESC, upvotes DESC").paginate(:per_page => PER_PAGE,:page => (params[:page] || 1))
```

or

```
users = User.members(current_user,params).order('updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") DESC, upvotes DESC').paginate(:per_page => PER_PAGE,:page => (params[:page] || 1))
```

or

```
users = User.members(current_user,params).order('updated_at.strftime("%F") DESC, upvotes DESC').paginate(:per_page => PER_PAGE,:page => (params[:page] || 1))
```